# PySpark - how to merge key with case ignored

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

In the word count example, for example I have `(python,1)` and `(Python,2)` after mapping. How can I merger the two into one `(python,3)` by doing the followings:

```
def combine(a, b):
    if a[0].lower() == b[0].lower():
        return (a[0], a[1] + b[1])
```

Then I call

```
(sc.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
    .reduce(lambda a, b :combine(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce` is not well suited here (it would require an additional `map` to a buffer that can handle intended aggregation) and it makes more sense to simply convert to lowercase inside the map:

```
from operator import add 

rdd = sc.parallelize([
   "Python", "python", "Haskell", "Clojure", "Scala", "scala"])
rdd.map(lambda word: (word.lower(), 1)).reduceByKey(add).collectAsMap()

## {'clojure': 1, 'haskell': 1, 'python': 2, 'scala': 2}
```